# Managing ad layer over all game scenes/layers

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

Im looking for a way to initilize an ad layer once and being able to control that layer's visibility through out my game scenes.  How is that usually done in cocos2dx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd consider making it a singleton and then just adding/removing it onto current scene when needed. You will have to remember to increase the retain count manually in constructor/`init()` and also have some cleanup method to decrease it so you don't have memory leaks.